# How can I add dropdown menu in a scrollable navigation without changing it effects?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I was editing this template which has a scrollable navigation. How can I add dropdown menu in the MEN, WOMEN and Children option without changing its current feature?

I tried using the dropdown class, I followed the instruction in getbootstrap.com but it still don't works. Can anyone help me on this?

Please someone tell me how I can add dropdown submenu on this website's navigation. Like under MEN, WOMEN and Children option but don't effect the scroll feature? Here is my HTML code:

```
<body id="page-top" class="index">

<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">Template 1</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="hidden">
                    <a href="#page-top"></a>
                </li>
               <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#men">MEN</a>
                </li>

                </li> 
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#women">WOMEN</a>
                </li>

               <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#children">CHILDREN</a>
                </li> 

               <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<!-- Header -->
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="intro-text">
            <div class="intro-lead-in">Welcome </div>
            <div class="intro-heading" style="font-size: 30px;">LOREM IPSUM SOMETHING</div>
            <a href="#men" class="page-scroll btn btn-xl">Whaa!?</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>


<section id="men" class="bg-light-gray">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h2 class="section-heading">Men Is Mortal.</h2>
                <h3 class="section-subheading text-muted">Isn't he?</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 men-item">
                <a href="#menModal1" class="men-link" data-toggle="modal">
                    <div class="men-hover">
                        <div class="men-hover-content">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus fa-3x"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <img src="img/men/h1.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                </a>
                <div class="men-caption">
                    <h4>heading</h4>
                    <p class="text-muted">caption</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 men-item">
                <a href="#menModal2" class="men-link" data-toggle="modal">
                    <div class="men-hover">
                        <div class="men-hover-content">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus fa-3x"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <img src="img/men/h1.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                </a>
                <div class="men-caption">
                    <h4>heading</h4>
                    <p class="text-muted">Caption</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 men-item">
                <a href="#menModal3" class="men-link" data-toggle="modal">
                    <div class="men-hover">
                        <div class="men-hover-content">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus fa-3x"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <img src="img/men/h1.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                </a>
                <div class="men-caption">
                    <h4>Heading</h4>
                    <p class="text-muted">Caption</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 men-item">
                <a href="#menModal4" class="men-link" data-toggle="modal">
                    <div class="men-hover">
                        <div class="men-hover-content">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus fa-3x"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <img src="img/men/h1.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                </a>
                <div class="men-caption">
                    <h4>heaing</h4>
                    <p class="text-muted">Caption</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 men-item">
                <a href="#menModal5" class="men-link" data-toggle="modal">
                    <div class="men-hover">
                        <div class="men-hover-content">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus fa-3x"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <img src="img/men/h1.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                </a>
                <div class="men-caption">
                    <h4>sdfdg</h4>
                    <p class="text-muted">Caption</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 men-item">
                <a href="#menModal6" class="men-link" data-toggle="modal">
                    <div class="men-hover">
                        <div class="men-hover-content">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus fa-3x"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <img src="img/men/h1.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                </a>
                <div class="men-caption">
                    <h4>dggdg</h4>
                    <p class="text-muted">Caption</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Here is the full code at codepen: http://codepen.io/msa208/pen/pJpzBW``

Comment: Let me remind you that the tag should be **twitter-bootstrap** and not **bootstrap**. Bootstrap is the program that boots to computer.

Comment: You can have either of one option - scroll on click of menu to target or show a dropdown? Which you want? Something like **[this](http://codepen.io/kshkrao3/pen/EjoxVG)**

Comment: Thank you very much! Thats what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple jquery plugin to achieve what you want.

http://www.smartmenus.org/

Here is a [demo](http://vadikom.github.io/smartmenus/src/demo/bootstrap-navbar.html) of the plugin.

Comment: Thanks! But how can I added it to the page?

Comment: If you have a look at the demo it gives you instructions on how to use this plugin. Everything you need to add to the page is highlighted in green. Basically the css at the top and scripts at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Shaiful Try this code:

I edited on pencode editor its successfully work as per you need.

Codepen Link:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPxNqB

Add this jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".navbar-nav > li").click(function () {
        $('.navbar-nav > li ul').not($(this).children("ul").toggle()).hide();
    });
});
```

Add this css code:

```
.navbar-nav > li ul{display:none; position:absolute; padding:0px 15px;}
.navbar-nav > li ul li{list-style:none;}
.navbar-default .nav li a{color:#777777;}
```

and this is your html code with drodown:

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">Template 1</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="hidden">
                    <a href="#page-top"></a>
                </li>
               <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#men">MEN</a>
                </li>

                </li> 
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#women">WOMEN</a>
                  <ul><li><a class="page-scroll" href="#children">CHILDREN</a></li>

                  <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#children">CHILDREN</a></li>
                    <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#children">CHILDREN</a></li>
                    <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#children">CHILDREN</a></li>

                  </ul>
                </li>

               <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#children">CHILDREN</a>
                </li> 

               <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<!-- Header -->
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="intro-text">
            <div class="intro-lead-in">Welcome </div>
            <div class="intro-heading" style="font-size: 30px;">LOREM IPSUM SOMETHING</div>
            <a href="#men" class="page-scroll btn btn-xl">Whaa!?</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>


<section id="men" class="bg-light-gray">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h2 class="section-heading">Men Is Mortal.</h2>
                <h3 class="section-subheading text-muted">Isn't he?</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 men-item">
                <a href="#menModal1" class="men-link" data-toggle="modal">
                    <div class="men-hover">
                        <div class="men-hover-content">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus fa-3x"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <img src="img/men/h1.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                </a>
                <div class="men-caption">
                    <h4>heading</h4>
                    <p class="text-muted">caption</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 men-item">
                <a href="#menModal2" class="men-link" data-toggle="modal">
                    <div class="men-hover">
                        <div class="men-hover-content">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus fa-3x"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <img src="img/men/h1.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                </a>
                <div class="men-caption">
                    <h4>heading</h4>
                    <p class="text-muted">Caption</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 men-item">
                <a href="#menModal3" class="men-link" data-toggle="modal">
                    <div class="men-hover">
                        <div class="men-hover-content">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus fa-3x"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <img src="img/men/h1.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                </a>
                <div class="men-caption">
                    <h4>Heading</h4>
                    <p class="text-muted">Caption</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 men-item">
                <a href="#menModal4" class="men-link" data-toggle="modal">
                    <div class="men-hover">
                        <div class="men-hover-content">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus fa-3x"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <img src="img/men/h1.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                </a>
                <div class="men-caption">
                    <h4>heaing</h4>
                    <p class="text-muted">Caption</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 men-item">
                <a href="#menModal5" class="men-link" data-toggle="modal">
                    <div class="men-hover">
                        <div class="men-hover-content">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus fa-3x"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <img src="img/men/h1.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                </a>
                <div class="men-caption">
                    <h4>sdfdg</h4>
                    <p class="text-muted">Caption</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 men-item">
                <a href="#menModal6" class="men-link" data-toggle="modal">
                    <div class="men-hover">
                        <div class="men-hover-content">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus fa-3x"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <img src="img/men/h1.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                </a>
                <div class="men-caption">
                    <h4>dggdg</h4>
                    <p class="text-muted">Caption</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```